# How to copy row in javascript with its style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to copy the last row with all its content including span & input with also the CSS classes, under the last row in the same table. How can I do this?

```js
$("#addRow").click(function() {
      var tableditTableName = '#AddCatTbl';
      var newID = parseInt($(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("id")) + 1;
      var x = $(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("style");
      var clone = $("table tr:last").clone();
      $(".tabledit-data span", clone).text("");
      $(".tabledit-data input", clone).val("");
      clone.appendTo("table");
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("id", newID);
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("style", x);
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last td .tabledit-span.tabledit-identifier").text('newID');
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last td .tabledit-input.tabledit-identifier").val('newID');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="AddCatTbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr id="22">
        <td><span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">22</span><input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="id" value="22" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Coconuts</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="Category Name" value="Coconuts" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Copra</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="Category Type" value="Copra" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;">
          <div class="tabledit-toolbar btn-toolbar" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="float: none;"><button type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><button type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-save-button btn btn-sm btn-success" style="display: none; float: none;">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-confirm-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none; float: none;">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-restore-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="display: none; float: none;">Restore</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
     <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
    </table>
```

Comment: your demo not working.. looks empty

Comment: $(“#AddCatTbl”).append($(“#AddCatTbl tr”).last()) are you looking for this??

Answer (score 0):

Declare the style you want as a *CSS* class & assign it to the cloned element you want, for example let `styleClass`:

```
.styleClass{
color:red
}
```

so instead of this:

```
$(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("style", x);
```

use this [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) jQuery function:

```
$(tableditTableName + " tr:last").addClass("styleClass");
```

here is A Demo:

```js
 $("#addRow").click(function() {
      var tableditTableName = '#AddCatTbl';
      var newID = parseInt($(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("id")) + 1;
      var x = $(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("style");
      var clone = $("table tr:last").clone();
      $(".tabledit-data span", clone).text("");
      $(".tabledit-data input", clone).val("");
      clone.appendTo("table");
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("id", newID);
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last").addClass("styleClass");
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last td .tabledit-span.tabledit-identifier").text(newID);
      $(tableditTableName + " tr:last td .tabledit-input.tabledit-identifier").val(newID);
    });
```

```css
.styleClass{
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="AddCatTbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr id="22">
        <td><span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">22</span><input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="id" value="22" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Coconuts</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="Category Name" value="Coconuts" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Copra</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="Category Type" value="Copra" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;">
          <div class="tabledit-toolbar btn-toolbar" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="float: none;"><button type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><button type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-save-button btn btn-sm btn-success" style="display: none; float: none;">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-confirm-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none; float: none;">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-restore-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="display: none; float: none;">Restore</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
     
    </table>
    <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you may want, if I understood your question right. Pardon me for the half vanilla JS! I just never felt like learning jQuery...

The comments should make the code self explanatory.

```js
$("#addRow").click(function() {
  var tableditTableName = '#AddCatTbl';
  var newID = parseInt($(tableditTableName + " tr:last").attr("id")) + 1;

  var clone = document.querySelector("table tr:last-of-type").cloneNode(true); // Create clone of last tr
  clone.setAttribute("id", newID); // Set its new id
  clone.setAttribute("class", "styleClass"); // Set its class to styleClass
  // Other modifications you made
  clone.querySelector("td .tabledit-span.tabledit-identifier").innerHTML = newID;
  clone.querySelector("td .tabledit-input.tabledit-identifier").value = newID;
  // Get the table and append the child
  var table = document.getElementById("AddCatTbl");
  table.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="AddCatTbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr id="22">
    <td><span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">22</span><input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="id" value="22" disabled=""></td>
    <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Coconuts</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="Category Name" value="Coconuts" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
    <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Copra</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="Category Type" value="Copra" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;">
      <div class="tabledit-toolbar btn-toolbar" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="float: none;"><button type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><button type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
        <button type="button" class="tabledit-save-button btn btn-sm btn-success" style="display: none; float: none;">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="tabledit-confirm-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none; float: none;">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" class="tabledit-restore-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="display: none; float: none;">Restore</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
</table>
```